# Angular lazy chunk files under multiple urls

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading

I have an Angular application with two lazy chunk files. I'm interested in hosting each of the lazy chunk files in two separate places, under two different URL paths. How to I specify both paths as places under which Angular should search for lazy chunk files?

Comment: That is not easily done. Maybe module federation is an option?

Comment: are you using universal or not? what lazy chunk file are you trying? lazyload module for dynamic component or lazyload theme or dynamic theme?